# A question related to the degree of vector field

Tags: dg.differential-geometry

Let $M$ is a $2n$-dim smooth Riemannian manifold, $\eta$ is a vector
field on $M$, $p\in M$ is a isolated zero of $\eta$. Then we can define a
map from $\partial B_{p}(\varepsilon)$ to $S^{2n-1}(1)$ by $\eta$:
$$\eta_{p}=\frac{\eta}{|\eta|}: \partial B_{p}(\varepsilon)\rightarrow S^{2n-1}(1)$$

Here $B_{p}(\varepsilon)$ is a ball about of $p$ with radius $\varepsilon$.

Let $f_1,\cdots,f_{2n-1}$ be an orthonormal basis of $T(\partial
B_{p}(\varepsilon))$, let $f^{*}_1,\cdots,f^{*}_{2n-1}$ be the
metric dual basis.

We can find that

$$\eta^{*}\wedge(\nabla^{TM}_{f_1}\eta)^{*}\wedge(\nabla^{TM}_{f_{2n-1}}\eta)^{*}$$

$$= (d{\rm vol}_{g^{TM}})\int^{B}\eta^{*}\wedge (\nabla^{TM}_{f_1}\eta)^{*}\wedge\cdots\wedge (\nabla^{TM}_{f_{2n-1}}\eta)^{*}$$

then

$$f^{\ast}_{1}\wedge\cdots\wedge f^{\ast}_{2n-1}\int^{B}\eta^{\ast}\wedge (\nabla^{TM}_{f_1}\eta)^{\ast}\wedge\cdots\wedge (\nabla^{TM}_{f_{2n-1}}\eta)^{\ast}=\eta^{\ast}_{p}\omega ,(1) $$

here $\omega$ be the volume form on $S^{2n-1}(1)$.

I find this formula (1) in the article “$\eta$-invariants and the
Poincaré-Hopf index formula”. But I don't know how to get it. Is
there some way to compute it?

Comment: You should explain your notations, because the map you first define does not make sense to me (you should explain how you identify the various tangent spaces with $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: Also, I guess $p$ is an *isolated* zero.

Comment: @Majer: Yes, $p$ is an isolated zero.
Kloechner:  the map $\eta_{p}$ is to unitization the tangent vector on $\partial
B_{p}(\varepsilon)$.

Comment: @Kloechner: Could you tell me why the map is no sense? Why i need to identify the various tangent spaces with $\mathbb{R}^{n}$? Thanks